# Is it possible to make the most recently-created sheet the default?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, if you have a "Spreadsheet", then you can make individual "Sheets" (like tabs) within it. In my Spreadsheet, I've made a new Sheet every month for the last four months, so January February March and April.
I want the April sheet to be the one that's open by default when I open the Spreadsheet, but January is always the default one open.
I've tried re-ordering the Sheets by dragging them, but no matter where I put the January one, it's always the first open, so I assume it's the default because it was the first created.

Does anyone know how I can make the April one (most-recently created) the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a Google spreadsheet is opened, it **always defaults to the first tab**.

I imagine that what you actually do is not opening the spreadsheet by clicking on it but using a bookmark.
But every single tab in a sheet has an identifier.

As an example, in a spreadsheet URL like:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CTdtIB_SVZj4Zo9zcI3-TZKAWYTLs/edit#gid=1209794310
```

- the long `1CTdtIB_SVZj4Zo9zcI3-TZKAWYTLs` is the **sheet ID** and
- the `1209794310` part is the **tab ID** within the sheet

I suppose you have bookmarked the specific sheet followed by the specific ID.
As a result when you click your bookmark, the sheet will always open on this tab which -since January was the first created- will always be the January tab.

What you can do though is **edit your bookmark and omit the tab ID** in the end

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CTdtIB_SVZj4Zo9zcI3-TZKAWYTLs/edit
```

**The sheet will now always open on the first tab.**

Comment: Besides using a bookmark, using the web browser autocomplete might also don't open other sheet when includes a tab id

Comment: Good point @Rubén

Comment: Perfect, problem solved, thanks!